# Dynamic of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}$) on $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

I imagine the dynamic of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}$) on $\mathbb{C}^2$ has been studied. Does one know if it is recurrent or ergodic (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) ? Is there any explicit description of the orbits ?

Thank you for your help,

Selim

Comment: -1 How does it act?

Comment: @MarcPalm I assume in the "obvious way" that 2x2 matrices act on a two-dimensional vector space?!

Comment: By linear transformation. Namely a matrix $
   \left (
   \begin{array}{cc}
      a & b \\
      c & d 
   \end{array}
   \right )
$ acts by $
   \left (
   \begin{array}{cc}
      a & b \\
      c & d 
   \end{array}
   \right )
\cdot 
   \left (
   \begin{array}{c}
      u  \\
      v
   \end{array}
   \right )
 = 
   \left (
   \begin{array}{c}
      au + bv \\
      cu + dv 
   \end{array}
   \right )
$. I thought it was obvious :)

Comment: Unless the question is not edited, I can't undo my downvote:(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since matrices from $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ are real, the action on $\mathbb C^2$ is the same as the diagonal action on the product of two copies of $\mathbb R^2$. Now, the action of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb R^2$ is well-known to be conjugate to its action on the space $H$ of horocycles in the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H^2$. The ergodic properties of the latter action are the same as for the horocycle flow on the quotient surface.

A single horocycle is determined by a point on the boundary circle of $\mathbb H^2$ and a real parameter (the "radius" of the horocycle). Two horocycles therefore determine a geodesic in $\mathbb H^2$ (which joins the centers of these horocycles) and two points on this geodesic (where it intersects these horospheres). Therefore, the action of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ on $H^2$ is conjugate to the product of its action on the unit tangent bundle of $\mathbb H^2$ and the trivial action on $\mathbb R$. Finally, the action of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ on $U\mathbb H^2$ is obviously dissipative.

Thus, the answer is that the action of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb C^2$ is dissipative, 
and its ergodic components ($\equiv$ orbits) are parameterized by the product of the unit tangent bundle of the quotient surface and $\mathbb R$.

Actually, the above argument shows that the action is not just dissipative, but also properly discontinuous.

Edit: Sorry, in the original answer forgot about one more copy of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The trivial action of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is the action by linear fractional transformations ?

Comment: No-no-no - what I mean is the really trivial action  - the one which does nothing.

Comment: It seems to me that your answer contains some confusions. The good reference is Ledrappier-Pollicott below. The linear action of SL(2,C) on $C^2$ is (up to some details) the isometric action of SL(2,C) on the space of horospheres of $H^3$. This action is not dissipative, and admits dense orbits for example.(You can replace $\C$ by $\R$ and $\H^3$ by $\H^2$ above)

Comment: Did you have a chance to notice that the OP asked about the action of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$? Or do you want to say that in this situation there is no difference between $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb Z$? If so, then you are definitely wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote my comment too fast; it contains many imprecisions.  In fact, my first reaction was due to te fact that I was confused by notations $H^2$ and $\mathbb{H}^2$ that I identified in a first reading.

Answer (score 4):

The dynamics are ergodic with respect to Lebesgue measure. See

> G. Hedlund, *Fuchsian groups and mixtures*, Ann. of Math. Volume 40, Number 2 (1939) 370-383, available [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968925).

If you prefer something with modern terminology, I'd recommend

> F. Ledrappier and M. Pollicott, *Ergodic properties of linear actions of (2×2)-matrices*, Duke Math. J. Volume 116, Number 2 (2003), 353-388, see [here](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.dmj/1085598272&page=record).